# Why function call twice in ASP.NET Web app

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a master and content page  and I have created an eventhandler on a master page that runs through the content page. And it calls twice. Why i dont understand so please help. even i have handled proper postback

When i call function sendmail() it is calling multiple time. please help where i am going to wrong

Master Page Code

```
namespace Report_Server
{
 public partial class ssrs : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
 {
     public delegate string NoArgEventHandler(string mailid);

     public static  event NoArgEventHandler sendMail    ;

     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {

     }
     protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {

         mailLabel.Visible = false;
         mailaddress.Visible = true;
         btnSendMail.Enabled = true;

         ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "mailModal", "$('#mailModal').modal();", true);
         //upModal.Update();
     }
     protected void btnSendMail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {



             //ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "mailModal", "$('#mailModal').modal('hide');", true);

             mailLabel.Visible = true;
             mailaddress.Visible = false;
             btnSendMail.Enabled = false;
             mailLabel.Text = "Sending, Please Wait";

             string message = sendMail(mailaddress.Text);
             mailLabel.Text = message;

             //Type cstype = this.GetType();

             //// Get a ClientScriptManager reference from the Page class.
             //ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;

             //// Check to see if the startup script is already registered.
             //if (!cs.IsStartupScriptRegistered(cstype, "PopupScript"))
             //{
             //    String cstext = string.Format("alert('{0}');",message);
             //    cs.RegisterStartupScript(cstype, "PopupScript", cstext, true);
             //}

             //string display = "Message Pop-up!";
             //ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" + display + "');", true);
         }

 }
}
```

Content Page code

```
namespace Report_Server.Reports.Vouchers.Pages
{
    public partial class Sales_Invoice : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                ssrs.sendMail += new ssrs.NoArgEventHandler(sendmail);

                ReportViewer ReportViewer1 = (ReportViewer)this.Master.FindControl("ReportViewer1");

                ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "Reports/Vouchers/Reports/Sale_Invoice_2.rdlc";

                var dc = new dsserp.reportlib.Vouchers();
                var mst = new dsserp.reportlib.Masters();
                TextBox mailaddress = (TextBox)Page.Master.FindControl("mailaddress");

                getParams();

                try
                {
                    ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
                    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();

                    requestparam.bill = dc.getSalesInvoice(requestparam.sdt, requestparam.edt, requestparam.dist_id, requestparam.acc_code, requestparam.from_no, requestparam.to_no, requestparam.page_no, requestparam.so_code);
                    if (mailaddress != null)
                        mailaddress.Text = requestparam.bill[0].d_email;

                    requestparam.branch = mst.getBranch();

                    ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource();
                    rds.Name = "DataSet1";
                    rds.Value = requestparam.bill;
                    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);

                    ReportDataSource rd2 = new ReportDataSource();
                    rd2.Name = "DataSet2";
                    rd2.Value = requestparam.branch;
                    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rd2);

                    ReportParameter[] p = new ReportParameter[13];

                    p[0] = new ReportParameter("firm_id", requestparam.firm_id.ToString());
                    p[1] = new ReportParameter("branch_id", requestparam.branch_id);
                    p[2] = new ReportParameter("div_id", requestparam.div_id);
                    p[3] = new ReportParameter("sdt", requestparam.sdt.ToShortDateString());
                    p[4] = new ReportParameter("edt", requestparam.edt.ToShortDateString());
                    p[5] = new ReportParameter("dist_id", requestparam.dist_id == null ? "null" : requestparam.dist_id.ToString());
                    p[6] = new ReportParameter("acc_code", requestparam.acc_code == null ? "null" : requestparam.acc_code.ToString());
                    p[7] = new ReportParameter("from_no", string.IsNullOrEmpty(requestparam.from_no) ? "null" : requestparam.from_no);
                    p[8] = new ReportParameter("to_no", string.IsNullOrEmpty(requestparam.to_no) ? "null" : requestparam.to_no);
                    p[9] = new ReportParameter("page", requestparam.page_no == null ? "-1" : requestparam.page_no.ToString());
                    p[10] = new ReportParameter("ismail", "2");
                    p[11] = new ReportParameter("UserId", requestparam.UserId);
                    p[12] = new ReportParameter("so_code", requestparam.so_code == null ? "null" : requestparam.so_code.ToString());

                    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(p);
                    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Response.Write(ex.Message);
                    Response.Write(ex.InnerException);
                }
            }
        }

        protected string sendmail(string mailid)
        {

            if (requestparam.mailSent == false)
            {
                string message = "Somthing Went Wrong";

                    var mailViewer1 = new ReportViewer();
                    mailViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "Reports\\Vouchers\\Reports\\Sale_Invoice_2.rdlc";


                    ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource();
                    rds.Name = "DataSet1";
                    rds.Value = requestparam.bill;
                    mailViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);

                    ReportDataSource rd2 = new ReportDataSource();
                    rd2.Name = "DataSet2";
                    rd2.Value = requestparam.branch;
                    mailViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rd2);

                    ReportParameter[] p = new ReportParameter[13];

                    p[0] = new ReportParameter("firm_id", requestparam.firm_id.ToString());
                    p[1] = new ReportParameter("branch_id", requestparam.branch_id);
                    p[2] = new ReportParameter("div_id", requestparam.div_id);
                    p[3] = new ReportParameter("sdt", requestparam.sdt.ToShortDateString());
                    p[4] = new ReportParameter("edt", requestparam.edt.ToShortDateString());
                    p[5] = new ReportParameter("dist_id", requestparam.dist_id == null ? "null" : requestparam.dist_id.ToString());
                    p[6] = new ReportParameter("acc_code", requestparam.acc_code == null ? "null" : requestparam.acc_code.ToString());
                    p[7] = new ReportParameter("from_no", string.IsNullOrEmpty(requestparam.from_no) ? "null" : requestparam.from_no);
                    p[8] = new ReportParameter("to_no", string.IsNullOrEmpty(requestparam.to_no) ? "null" : requestparam.to_no);
                    p[9] = new ReportParameter("page", "1");
                    p[10] = new ReportParameter("ismail", "1");
                    p[11] = new ReportParameter("UserId", requestparam.UserId);
                    p[12] = new ReportParameter("so_code", requestparam.so_code == null ? "null" : requestparam.so_code.ToString());


                    //TextBox mailaddress = (TextBox)Page.Master.FindControl("mailaddress");
                    //Label mailLabel = (Label)Page.Master.FindControl("mailLabel");
                    message = "Something Went Wrong";

                    bool smtpFound = false;

                    var mst = new dsserp.reportlib.Masters();

                    var Branch = requestparam.branch[0];

                    smptuser user = new smptuser();

                    try
                    {


                        user.displayName = Branch.smtp_displyname;
                        user.hostName = Branch.smtp_host;
                        user.userId = Branch.smtp_UserId;
                        user.Password = password.DecryptPass(Branch.smtp_Password);
                        user.mailAddress = Branch.smtp_mailAddress;
                        user.Port = Convert.ToInt32(Branch.smtp_port);
                        if (user.Port > 0)
                            smtpFound = true;


                        if (smtpFound)
                        {
                            var emailFound = string.IsNullOrEmpty(mailid) == false;
                            if (emailFound)
                            {
                                string filename = requestparam.from_no;
                                if (requestparam.from_no != requestparam.to_no)
                                {
                                    filename = filename + "-" + requestparam.to_no;
                                }
                                string body = "Dear Sir/Maa'm" + "\r\n" + "\r\n" + "A copy of the invoice " + filename + " has been attached for your reference.";
                                var _file = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), filename + ".pdf");
                                export export = new export();
                                mailViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(p);

                                export.toFile(mailViewer1.LocalReport, _file);


                                message = mail.send(_file, mailid, "Invoice No:" + filename, body, user); //"Success:sent" 

                            }
                            else
                                message = " Email Address Not Found, Please try again";
                        }

                        else
                            message = "No SMTP Server Found";


                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {

                        message = "No SMTP Server Found";

                    }
                    if (message == "sent")
                        message = "Successfuly mail sent";

                requestparam.response= message;
            }
            return requestparam.response;
        }

        public void getParams()
        {
            string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ReportServerEntities"].ConnectionString;

            requestparam.firm_id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["firm_id"]);
            requestparam.branch_id = Request.QueryString["branch_id"];
            requestparam.div_id = Request.QueryString["div_id"];
            requestparam.sdt = Convert.ToDateTime(Request.QueryString["sdt"]);
            requestparam.edt = Convert.ToDateTime(Request.QueryString["edt"]);

            requestparam.dist_id = null;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["dist_id"]))
                requestparam.dist_id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["dist_id"]);

            requestparam.acc_code = null;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["acc_code"]))
                requestparam.acc_code = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["acc_code"]);

            requestparam.from_no = Request.QueryString["from_no"];
            requestparam.to_no = Request.QueryString["to_no"];
            requestparam.UserId = Request.QueryString["User"];


            requestparam.page_no = null;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["page_no"]))
                requestparam.page_no = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["page_no"]);

            requestparam.so_code = null;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["so_code"]))
                requestparam.so_code = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["so_code"]);

            properties.connectionstring = conn;
            properties.firm_id = requestparam.firm_id;
            properties.branch_id = requestparam.branch_id;
            properties.div_id = requestparam.div_id;


        }


        public static class requestparam
        {
            public static int firm_id { get; set; }
            public static string branch_id { get; set; }
            public static string div_id { get; set; }
            public static string from_no { get; set; }
            public static string to_no { get; set; }
            public static string UserId { get; set; }
            public static DateTime sdt { get; set; }
            public static DateTime edt { get; set; }
            public static int? dist_id { get; set; }
            public static int? acc_code { get; set; }
            public static int? page_no { get; set; }
            public static int? so_code { get; set; }
            public static int? ismail { get; set; }
            public static List<Voucher.salesInvoice> bill { get; set; }
            public static List<Master.Branch> branch { get; set; }
            public static  bool mailSent { get; set; }
            public static string  response { get; set; }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Seeing the relevant code would make it a lot easier to understand

Comment: Welcome to the forum. Please post some relevant code and we may be able to help you.